# Identify instances of a stack under same environment through chef

Tags: chef-infra

I have two stacks (each stack with 2 web instances, 2 app instances). Lets say, my stacks are  `abc-dev-01` and `abc-dev-02`.

Instances under stacks are,

```
abc-dev-01-app01
abc-dev-01-app02
abc-dev-01-web01
abc-dev-01-web02

abc-dev-02-app01
abc-dev-02-app02
abc-dev-02-web01
abc-dev-02-web02
```

All are under same environment "dev" . I have to place app01's ipaddress in my nginx configuration. I did a chef search using role

```
webserver = search(:node, "role:xyz-app")
```

But this search will return two ipaddress(one is of `abc-dev-01-app01` and other is of `abc-dev-02-app01`).

But for stack abc-dev-01  I need to  get only the ipaddress of `abc-dev-01-app01`.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

`knife search node "role:xyz-app AND name:*dev-01*"`

Having two different stacks in the same environment is going to be a pain to manage. I would suggest having `dev1` and `dev2` environments.

Comment: Or just tag the machines with their stack name, the node object has tag and tagged? methods for this.

Comment: something similar is what I have ended up doing at the end. I have created a attribute "stackname:<>" and associated that attribute to each instance from chef server. Is there a better way of doing this from chef server manually ?

Comment: Chef 'tag' can be used rather than adding an attribute. You can use knife to tag a node. You should then be able to search based on a tag.